# Error when selecting items out of order from a catalog

Tags: java, arrays, class, user-input

I am creating a program in Java where a customer picks items from a catalog. They can choose items in any order and how many they want, they can even select an item twice and it will add the two quantities and make it one total. The problem I am having is when selecting an item, the code errors when I select them out of order. It only works when I select item 1, then item 2, and so on.

name is an array that holds the names of the items.

quantity is an array that holds the amount of a selected item. Preferably, the amount of the item should be in the same position as the name of the item is in the array called name.

```
public static double[] addD(int n, double arr[], double x) {
   int i;   

   double newarr[] = new double[n + 1];

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       newarr[i] = arr[i];

   newarr[n] = x;

   return newarr;
}




 do {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    System.out.println("Select the number of the product you would like and once you are finished enter the number to checkout.\n");
    ItemNumber = myObj.nextInt();  // Read user input
    while (ItemNumber <= name.length)
    if (ItemNumber < (name.length + 1))
    {
        System.out.println("How many would you like?\n");
        ItemQuantity = myObj.nextDouble();
        ItemName = name[ItemNumber - 1];
        quantity = addD(quantity.length, quantity, ItemQuantity);
        System.out.println("\nThe customer picks " + Math.round(quantity[ItemNumber - 1]) + " " + ItemName + "(s)\n");
        break;
    }
} while (ItemNumber <= name.length);
```

Comment: "the code errors" you may want to include the error with the question.

Comment: This is the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Answer (score 0):

ItemNumber could be larger than the length of quantity. You want to print the last value in quantity (although I'm pretty sure there are more mistakes here). This will fix your IndexOutOfBoundsError.

```
{
    System.out.println("How many would you like?\n");
    ItemQuantity = myObj.nextDouble();
    ItemName = name[ItemNumber - 1];
    quantity = addD(quantity.length, quantity, ItemQuantity);
    System.out.println("\nThe customer picks " + Math.round(quantity[quantity.length - 1]) + " " + ItemName + "(s)\n");
     break;
}
```